# Determine the angles of the form $k (\pi)$

Tags: geometry

Determine the angles of the form $k (\pi)$ with rational $k$ such that the results of its sines are rational

This is an application of Niven's theorem.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is an application of Niven's theorem. That theorem gives the list of those $k\in\mathbb Q\cap\left[0,\frac12\right]$ for which $\sin(k\pi)\in\mathbb Q$. It happens that that list consists of $\left\{0,\frac16,\frac12\right\}$. It is now easy to determine those $k\in[-1,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ for which $\sin(k\pi)\in\mathbb Q$. And then we use the fact that the sine function is periodic with period $2\pi$.

Comment: I don't think it changes much, since $ sin (kx) = cos (\pi / (2-kx))$

Comment: I misunderstood your question. What do you think now?

Comment: Yess ! Thanks! oo